# Ignore first line

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex pattern that ignores the first line, for example:

```
test
test
test
```

Should match the last two **test test**, the first one should be skipped.

Comment: @gpojd PHP is what I'm using.

Comment: Are you processing a file or what is the input?

Comment: good read http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: My guess would be take everything after the first occurrence of \n\r and ignore anything that comes before it? I guess we need more information from `Aborted` because how are people to know what they use for End of Line, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?!\A)^.*\Z
```

with multiline `m` and singleline (dot-all) `s` modifiers

so in PHP

```
/(?!\A)^.*\Z/ms
```

Comment: nothing like adding complexity when it isn't needed.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - You don't like it? I can make it even shorter: `/(?!\A)^.*/ms` :)

Comment: @Omega oh dont worry I do like it :) .  I just think there are simpler solutions than forcing that type of logic into the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clouding up your regex, just eat the first line in the program that feeds the regex.  Untested code as follows:

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");
$throwAway = fgets($file_handle);
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   yourMagicFunction($line);
  }
fclose($file_handle);
```

Code taken from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/)

I generally recommend the easier to manage process.  The concern has to be that the next maintainer of your regex looks at it and wonders why it chomps the first line instead of letting a separate program do that function.

Comment: @Aborted Let me go google how to read a line in PHP and update my answer.  Are you processing files or what?

Comment: @Aborted updated to use PHP code to show how it should work, the solution is untested.